# Fade in/out elements in same place

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I have an unordered list that is set to fullscreen, each li has a repeated background pattern. I'd like each li to fade in/ out every 20 seconds as soon as the page is loaded. My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uWwfv/1/

I've tried the css way (absolute positioning of my li elements) but it doesn't work with my fullscreen script so would need pure jQuery to fade in/out each li. How might I do this?

**Fullscreen code is:**

```
function fitElements() {

var height = $(window).height();

var width = $(window).width();

$('ul#fullscreen-slider li').css('height', height);

$('ul#fullscreen-slider li').css('width', width);

};


$(document).ready(function() {
fitElements();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<section id="home">
    <ul id="fullscreen-slider">
        <li><h1 class="cherry-red"><span>Slide 1</span></h1></li>
        <li><h1 class="cherry-red"><span>slide 2</span></h1></li>
        <li><h1 class="cherry-red"><span>slide 3</span></h1></li>
        <li><h1 class="cherry-red"><span>slide 4</span></h1></li>
        <li><h1 class="cherry-red"><span>slide 5 - when complete fade to slide 1</span></h1></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**NOTE:** I wanted to stay away from using a heavy plugin especially when most don't cater for the background-repeat behaviour.

Comment: why u can't use `$('selector').fadeIn(function(){ $(this).fadeOut(); });` method..?? call it on an interval using javascript.

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to JS so i'm not sure how to go about doing that...

Comment: I don't get exactly what effect you would like to achieve .. `:/`
You want all the li to slide in then immediatly out every 20 sec ?

Comment: I think u r trying to develop a slide show using jQuery. It that right..?

Comment: Yes but without the heavy-ness of a plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS function

```
function slideshow() {
    $('#fullscreen-slider li:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('#fullscreen-slider :first-child').fadeOut().next('li').fadeIn().end().appendTo('#fullscreen-slider');}, 3000);
}
```

As for CSS, added `position:relative;` to UL, `position:absolute; left:0; top:0;` to LIs and added a class with the background for each LI.

The only thing you need to change is that each li needs its class for its background instead of using nth-child, because this code is now messing with the li's organization, by getting the just faded one and appending in the end again (therefore the visible one would always be `nth-child(0)`).

This is a slight modified version of [Simplest jQuery Slideshow](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow) by Jonathan Snook.

Here is my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jRDkm/1/

Comment: This looks great thanks, I did notice though that it doesn't repeat when it gets to the end? It repeats the first li but then fades out to a white background and stops? How could this be fixed so its continually looping?

Comment: No problems, the selector was wrong. Thanks for your code! See here for correct selector: http://jsfiddle.net/jRDkm/5/

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function to do that and call it using setInterval.

Then, when all your page is loaded, call the clearInterval function to stop blinking.

http://jsfiddle.net/uWwfv/4/

```
function fadeBlinking() {
    $('li').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });
}

var intervalHandle = setInterval(function () {
    fadeBlinking();
}, 20000);

fadeBlinking();

$(document).ready(function () {
    fitElements();

    //Stop blinking when your condition is met
    clearInterval(intervalHandle)
});
```

Comment: It is not a "plug and play" piece of code, but try this one : http://jsfiddle.net/uWwfv/4/